# How to turn a JSX.element to a number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a small webapp(REACT) for my group of friends. the goal is to display a leaderboard using firebase to store data.

I've print the leaderboard and did a function to follow the numeric order here

```
const data = [
  { Nom: "Pepper", Photo: <Photo />, PTS: <Admin /> },
  { Nom: "Alice", Photo: <AliceArr />, PTS: <AliceScore /> },
  { Nom: "Maxime", Photo: 29, PTS: 5 },
  { Nom: "Steve", Photo: <SteveArr />, PTS: 0 },
  { Nom: "Kath", Photo: 19, PTS: 5 },
  { Nom: "Cath", Photo: 19, PTS: 6 },
  { Nom: "Eliane", Photo: 19, PTS: 0 },
  { Nom: "Raph", Photo: 19, PTS: 0 },
  { Nom: "Emy", Photo: <EmyArr />, PTS: 12 },
  { Nom: "Charles", Photo: 19, PTS: 0 },
  { Nom: "Youri", Photo: 19, PTS: 0 },
  { Nom: "Mari", Photo: 19, PTS: 0 },
  { Nom: "Yanni", Photo: 19, PTS: 0 },
  { Nom: "Mede", Photo: 19, PTS: 0 },
  { Nom: "Anom", Photo: 19, PTS: 0 },
];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (b.PTS < a.PTS) return -1;
  if (b.PTS > a.PTS) return 1;
  return 0;
});

function Leader() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>LEADERBOARD</header>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Nom</th>
          <th>Photo</th>
          <th>PTS</th>
        </tr>
        {data.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <tr key={key}>
              <td>{val.Nom}</td>
              <td>{val.Photo}</td>
              <td>{val.PTS}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Leader;
```

And i've achieved the fetch in Firestore with this code:

```
function Admin() {
  const [scorePep, setScorePep] = useState<NewType[]>([]);
  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(PepperScore, (snapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
        setScorePep(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            return {
              PTS: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
            };
          })
        );
      }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {scorePep.map((item) => (
        <div>{item.PTS}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Admin;
```

My problem is when i input  to display the PTS from Firebase the function i've build to keep the highest score at the top doesn't work anymore. I think it's because everything coming from firebase is a string but everything i've tried to turn it into an integer failed...

Thank you!

I've tried the ReactDOMserver to turn it into a string and then an Interger.

Every manipulation to the function makes the webapp crash..

Comment: I'm confused on why you have some jsx elements as a value and others as a number. What are these components and what are you trying to achieve beyond turning them into a number, which is equally as confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,  in the const data =[] if you look a the first data "Pepper" i use <admin/> to display the score i fetch from firebase. the number i fetch is 4 which should drop this player lower than other ones with numbers. The same thing should happen to "alice" which i use <AliceScore/> to display the score of 3. When i input a numerical value to PTS myself, the leaderboard works and put everyone in numerical orders. When i use a jsx element like <Admin/> to fetch a number, it doesnt work..

Comment: @Dplayerz Perhaps I have misunderstood but it just seems weird - does that mean the `<number>` in other people’s `Photo` and `PTS` keys are just placeholders?

Comment: yes, i'm testing with only the two at the top (Alice, Pepper)..

Comment: @Dplayerz Could you mention more about what have you tried so far to turn it into number and what the error is?

Comment: Why not keep everything as a number and conditionally render the component, passing the number as a prop? Seems easier than jumping through hoops to turn a jsx element into a number